# Отправка сообщений в группу Telegram

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, telebot

Необходимо через команду бота `/post` отправить сообщение в группу (группы).
Сообщения могут быть произвольного размера и содержать в себе изображение\ссылки\аудиофайлы\документы

Не могу понять, как написать функцию отправки сообщения, используя `pyTelegramBotAPI`.

Как можно это реализовать? Заранее спасибо!

***Мой код:***

```py
import telebot


token = ''
bot = telebot.TeleBot(token)


@bot.message_handler(commands=['start', 'post'])
def command(message):
        if message.text == '/start':
           bot.reply_to(message, "Command START is working ")
        elif message.text == '/post':
           chat_id = ''
           bot.send_message(chat_id, message, text)


@bot.message_handler(content_types=["new_chat_members"])
def handler_new_member(message):
    user_name = message.new_chat_member.first_name 
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f"Welcome, {user_name}!")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, приведите Ваш код и уточните, что конкретно вызывает у Вас затруднения.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***РЕШЕНИЕ***

```py
import telebot

token = 'TOKEN_HERE'
bot = telebot.TeleBot(token)


@bot.message_handler(commands=['post'])
def command(message):
    if message.text.split(" ", 1)[0] == "/post":
        chat_id = 'CHAT_ID_HERE'
        bot.send_message(chat_id, message.text.split(" ", 1)[1])


@bot.message_handler(content_types=["new_chat_members"])
def handler_new_member(message):
    user_name = message.new_chat_member.first_name
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f"Welcome, {user_name}!")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```